# Multi-line grep beween two tags, only show the last match

Tags: sed, grep, awk

I'm having a program that intermingles data segments into log output:

```
log message
log message
----BEGIN INLINE DATA----
data
data
data
-----END INLINE DATA-----
log messge
```

I'm looking for something like,

```
awk '/-BEGIN INLINE DATA-/,/-END INLINE DATA-/'
```

but it should only print the last data segment, and without the surrounding 'tags'.

Comment: If the data lines are complex please expand your example to show one of them.

Comment: @awkward_grep I'm guessing your choice of user name was influenced by this? :)

Answer (score 2):

With awk, start accumulating data after a start marker and stop when you encounter an end marker. Reinitialize the data accumulator if you encounter a new start marker.

```
awk '
    /-BEGIN INLINE DATA-/ {data = ""; storing = 1}
    /-END INLINE DATA-/ {storing = 0}
    storing {data = data "\n" $0}
    END {print data}
'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe two seds like this:

```
<your program> | tac | sed '1,/END INLINE DATA/d' | sed '/BEGIN INLINE DATA/,$d' | tac
```

Comment: but this will only print one line

Comment: Sorry, I misread. Just omit the tail at the end and it should pick the first data block.

Comment: Duh, you want the last block. Just use tac before and after the seds.

Answer (score 0):

```
tac log.txt | sed '1,/END INLINE DATA/d' | sed '/BEGIN INLINE DATA/,$d' | tac
```

seems to do the job

Comment: I'm guessing this is taken from Karol's answer. If the answer has helped you, the correct way of indicating this is to mark it as accepted (use the tick box below the voting markers next to the question). Please note that Stack Exchange format is different from conventional forums.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to get what you want:

```
$ sed -n '/BEGIN/,/END/p' < data.txt | sed '1d;$d' | tail -1
data
```

#### Details

The `sed` command prints all the lines (inclusive) between the BEGIN and END lines. The 2nd `sed` command chops off the first and last lines, while the `tail` command returns the last line.

#### Alternatives

You could easily use your `awk` line as well:

```
$ awk '/-BEGIN INLINE DATA-/,/-END INLINE DATA-/'  data.txt | sed '1d;$d' | tail -1
data
```

Comment: But the OP doesn't want the last line (s)he wants the last data block.

Comment: @JosephR. - yeah that's why I asked him/her to add an example of the "data" segment/line/whatever it is so we could make sure our solutions were apt.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rather unorthodox way of doing it in Perl:

```
perl -ne '
  BEGIN{ $/="----BEGIN INLINE DATA----\n" } # Set input record separator

  $payload= s/----END INLINE DATA----.*\z//rs; # Remove end marker and messages

  END{ print $payload } # Print the last payload

' file
```

This needs Perl v5.14 or higher. If you're stuck with an older version of Perl you'll need an extra line:

```
perl -ne '
  BEGIN{ $/="----BEGIN INLINE DATA----\n" } # Set input record separator

  $payload= $_; # Copy current line into $payload
  $payload=~ s/----END INLINE DATA----.*\z//s; # Remove end marker and messages

  END{ print $payload } # Print the last payload

' file
```